# Time stamp and composition time offset

Tags: h.264

Does H.264 buffer contains Time stamp and decoding time stamp information.
when we get the H.264 nalu data does that contain timing information in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean raw H.264 NAL units than no they don't contain timing information if mean something like PTS/DTS. Timestamps are on higher level in containers like MKV/MP4/TS. The only time related information in H.264 specs afaik are num_units_in_tick/time_scale in VUI that can be used to finding FPS in case of constant frame rate (fixed_frame_rate_flag = 1), and some fields in Picture timing SEI but as they are optional and not really well specified so nobody really use them.

Comment: So how to find the Timing information. If I get IPPBPPBPPB... frames from my encoder( I use ipp samples ) Then what is the timestamp and composition time offset to be used to make it a RTMP stream packet.

Comment: I am dunno about IPP encoder. Usually timing information is inputted to and outputted from encoder by side channel (i.e. not in NALs but in more higher level structures). For example in x264 you send frames with associated PTS (i_pts in x264_picture_t of input picture) to encoder and encoder outputs frame NALs with associated PTS/DTS (i_pts/i_dts in x264_picture_t of output picture).