# libx264 encoder video plays too fast

Tags: video, encoding, x264

I'm trying to write a program that uses libx264 to encode the video frames. I've wrapped this code into a small class (see below). I have frames that are in YUV420 format. libx264 encodes the frames and I save them to a file. I can play the file back in VLC, all of the frames are there, but it plays back at several hundred times the actual frame rate. Currently I am capturing frames at 2.5 FPS, but they play back as if it was recorded at 250 or more FPS. I've tried to change the frame rate with no luck.

I've also tried to set

```
_param.b_vfr_input = 1
```

and then set the time bases appropriately, but that causes my program to crash. Any ideas? My encode code is shown below. I've also included the output of ffprobe -show_frames

Wrapper Class:

```
x264wrapper::x264wrapper(int width, int height, int fps, int timeBaseNum, int timeBaseDen, int vfr)
{
    x264_param_default_preset(&_param, "veryfast", "zerolatency");
    _param.i_threads = 1;
    _param.i_width = width;
    _param.i_height = height;
    _param.i_fps_num = fps;
    _param.i_fps_den = 1;
    // Intra refres:
    _param.i_keyint_max = fps;
    _param.b_intra_refresh = 1;
    //Rate control:
    _param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CRF;
    //_param.rc.i_rc_method = X264_RC_CQP;
    _param.rc.f_rf_constant = 25;
    _param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = 35;
    //For streaming:
    _param.b_repeat_headers = 1;
    _param.b_annexb = 1;    
    // misc
    _param.b_vfr_input = vfr;
    _param.i_timebase_num = timeBaseNum; 
    _param.i_timebase_den = timeBaseDen;

    _param.i_log_level = X264_LOG_DEBUG;

    _encoder = x264_encoder_open(&_param);

    cout << "Timebase " << _param.i_timebase_num << "/" << _param.i_timebase_den << endl;
    cout << "fps " << _param.i_fps_num << "/" << _param.i_fps_den << endl;
    _ticks_per_frame = (int64_t)_param.i_timebase_den * _param.i_fps_den / _param.i_timebase_num / _param.i_fps_num;
    cout << "ticks_per_frame " << _ticks_per_frame << endl;
    int result = x264_picture_alloc(&_pic_in, X264_CSP_I420, width, height);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        cout << "Failed to allocate picture" << endl;
        throw(1);
    }

    _ofs = new ofstream("output.h264", ofstream::out | ofstream::binary);
    _pts = 0;
}


x264wrapper::~x264wrapper(void)
{
    _ofs->close();
}



void x264wrapper::encode(uint8_t * buf)
{
    x264_nal_t* nals;
    int i_nals;
    convertFromBalserToX264(buf);
    _pts += _ticks_per_frame;
    _pic_in.i_pts = _pts;
    x264_picture_t pic_out;
    int frame_size = x264_encoder_encode(_encoder, &nals, &i_nals, &_pic_in, &pic_out);
    if (frame_size >= 0)
    {
        _ofs->write((char*)nals[0].p_payload, frame_size);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "error: x264_encoder_encode failed" << endl;
    }
}
```

Output of ffprobe -show_frames:

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=N/A
pkt_pts_time=N/A
pkt_dts=N/A
pkt_dts_time=N/A
pkt_duration=48000
pkt_duration_time=0.040000
pkt_pos=0
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=0
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
reference=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
key_frame=0
pkt_pts=N/A
pkt_pts_time=N/A
pkt_dts=N/A
pkt_dts_time=N/A
pkt_duration=N/A
pkt_duration_time=N/A
pkt_pos=54947
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=1
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
reference=0
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
media_type=video
key_frame=0
pkt_pts=N/A
pkt_pts_time=N/A
pkt_dts=N/A
pkt_dts_time=N/A
pkt_duration=N/A
pkt_duration_time=N/A
pkt_pos=57899
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=2
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
reference=0
[/FRAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you output raw Annex B stream i.e. you don't mux it in any container like mkv/mp4. As I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709183/time-stamp-and-composition-time-offset) raw Annex B streams don't have any timing information inside other few values in header (VUI) which can be used to find out constant frame rate but wouldn't work in case of variable frame rate (it may result in playing at speed of timebase and not real fps). If you have problems with constant frame rate (param.b_vfr_input = 0) also than make sure that you use good decoder/player because in past VLC have problems with playing raw Annex B streams (it was doubling frame rate but not speed up hundred times). You can also try to mux your stream with MKVToolnix and look which fps it will detect.